# Почему индекс Elasticsearch не заполняется данными?

Tags: elasticsearch

Проблема проста настолько же, насколько абсурдна: я не могу добавить данные в индекс elasticsearch. Для добавления использую следующую команду:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bid_portal/auction/1?pretty' -d '{"test": 1}'
```

Получаю результат:

```
{
  "_index" : "bid_portal",
  "_type" : "auction",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "created" : true
}
```

Запрашиваю индекс на наличие данных в нём следующей командой:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/bid_portal/auctions/_search?pretty' -d '{"query": {"match_all": {}}}'
```

Результат:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: соответствующий health для индекса yellow/green?

Comment: в своем запросе вы указываете auction**s**, в то время как отправляете сущность в auction без s

Comment: Нашёл проблему. Я добавлял документ в тип action, а запрашивал документы из типа action**S**. Сейчас всё нормально ищется. Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: о чем я и написал